# JQuery Multiple Request with Progress Bar

Tags: jquery, ajax, url, progress-bar

I am trying to figure out how to code a progress bar in JQuery and performing multiple tasks. I have the tasks already programmed, for example:

http://example.com/api/task1.php  -> returns success / fail header
http://example.com/api/task2.php  -> returns success / fail header
etc...

Here's what it will do. Person submits value (IP Address), then I have about 10 different "checks" the services do. After each check, the /api/'s will return success header and then I want the progress bar to update, 10%, 20% etc.

I am guessing something like this, is this close?

```
$(function() { 
$("#form").submit(function(){
   var url= $("#url").val();
   var submitvalue= 'url='+ url;
        $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "/api/task1.php",
        data: submitvalue, 
        cache: false,
        success: function(html){
            event.preventDefault();
            progressbar(10);
            runtask2();
        }
   }
  }
 }
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: What happens when you test it?

Comment: well, it's not working.. lots of errors. i am very rusty. i'll keep trying.

Comment: The more details you provide, the better help you'll get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's what I came up with, this has been made generic enough for others to use. It does use JQuery and the JQuery UI

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>


<script>

var did; // global variable

// Step 1 - first check

$( "#signup1" ).submit(function( event ) {

    // Stop form from submitting normally
        event.preventDefault();

    // Get user value from URL Field in form signup1
        url = $("#url").val();

    // Page to submit request to
        page = "/scripts/signup/1.php";

    // Set progress bar status
        $('#status').text('Performing Task 1..');
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 10 });

    // Send the data to the page
        var posting = $.post( page, { url: url } );

        posting.done(function( data ) {
            console.log(data); // for debugging
            did = (data); // this is needed to perform the other checks

    // move progress bar a little more
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 20 });

    // move on to next process 
        check2();

  });
});

// additional checks formatted like this...

function check2() {
    $('#status').text('Performing Task 2..');
    page = "/scripts/signup/2.php";
    var posting = $.post( page, { id: did } );

    posting.done(function( data ) {
        console.log(data);  // debugging
        var content = $( data );
        $('#progressbar').progressbar({ value: 30 });
        })
    }

</script>
```